# Почему куча-мала пишется через дефис?

Tags: орфография, стилистика

Это мое творчество, мини-рассказ.

***Как люди…***

*Высыпаю на асфальт  чищеные семечки из пакетика, ожидая  вполне предсказуемый  аншлаг. Но голуби стоят чуть в стороне, не подходят. Крутят головками, косятся друг на друга – никто не решается быть первым. Удивительно!*

*Но вот подошел один, неуверенно клюнул, за ним другой…   Минуты не прошло, а здесь уже двухэтажная **куча мала** из голубей.*

Ошибка в тексте!  Вот уж не ожидала. **И почему это *куча-мала* пишется через дефис?** А может, есть еще и стилистические ошибки?

Comment: Да уж, и сам не ожидал... И сочетание непопулярное... Скорее всего, так исторически сложилось.

Comment: Либо я что-то не так понял, либо Вы случайно пропустили букву „д” в слове „подходят” в четвёртой строке.

Comment: Спасибо, исправила. А почему сочетание непопулярное? Вроде бы обычное, разговорное выражение. Вот, кстати, раздельное написание   https://phraseology.academic.ru/5983/Куча_мала   Вот пример: А « концептов» здесь ― куча мала (= много).. Любоваться машинами ...можно по каталогу.  Может быть,  детская игра пишется через дефис, а при других значениях написание раздельное?

Comment: Под „непопулярностью” я имел в виду очень малое количество поисковых запросов в Интернете. Но всё же насчёт написания, как мне кажется, однозначного ответа нет.

Comment: Хотя тот же „Викисловарь”, кстати говоря, рекомендует раздельное написание, но оно ничем не обосновано, в отличие от предложенного Вами ресурса.